# ModelForm saving value of submit button to database

Tags: python, django, forms, model

I have a form in my project that just wouldnt grab whatever the user typed in and im stumped for why

no matter what i typed into the input field, the string 'Post' is what gets saved into the database, which is the value of the submit button, nd whatever i changed the value to is also what gets saved.

**model**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    post = models.TextField(max_length=250)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.author}, {self.date_time}, {self.post}"
```

**form**

```
class NewPostForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['post']
```

**views.py**

```
def index(request):

    newpostform = NewPostForm()

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        username = request.user.get_username()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        post = Post(author=username)
        newpostform = NewPostForm(request.POST,request.FILES, instance=post)
        if newpostform.is_valid():
            post = newpostform.save()
            return render(request, "network/index.html")

    return render(request, "network/index.html", {
        "newpostform": newpostform
    })
```

**html**

```
> <form action="{% url 'index' %}" method="post">
>             {% csrf_token %}
>             <div>
>                 {{ newpostform }}
>             </div>
>             <input id='post-btn' class="btn btn-primary" name="post" type="submit" value="Post">
>         </form>
```

Comment: Remove the name from your submit button

Comment: This is because you are specifying only `fields = ['post']` in your forms `class Meta`. This means that only post will be captured